# login and logout events on server side in ria services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using standard built-in forms authentication in silverlight business application. 
On the client side we have:

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoggedIn += (s, e) =>
{
 ...
}
```

and

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoggedOut += (s, e) =>
{
 ...
}
```

My question is: is it possible to catch login and logout events on the **server** side?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a service with methods you can call on every action.